# Math.random called from for loop produces continous "random" numbers

Tags: java, for-loop, random

im pretty new to java stuff. At the moment i am trying to write a programm dealing with the birthday problem(wikipedia). I want to know how many people have to be asked for their day and month of birth until one is duplicate.
I wrote a class doing the "asking" with the following code:

```
    public class Starter {

    static ArrayList<Integer> peeps = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static boolean match = false;
    static int counter = 0;

    public static int doRand() {
        int rand = (1 + (int) (Math.random() * ((365 - 1) + 1)));
        return rand;
    }

    public static int start() {

        do {
            int buffer = 0;
            buffer = doRand();
            if (peeps.isEmpty()) {
                peeps.add(doRand());
            }
            counter++;

            for (int i = 0; i < peeps.size(); i++) {

                if (peeps.get(i) == buffer) {
                    match = true;
                }
            }
            peeps.add(buffer);

        } while (match == false);

        return counter;
    }

}
```

This seems to work and produces numbers somewhat between 10 and 50.
But if I run this function from the following for-loop, I get really strange result:

```
    public class BirtdayProblem {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i=0;i< 1000;i++) {

             System.out.println(Starter.start());
        }
     }
}
```

It produces an output of 1000 continous numbers...why?
If I run the function multiple times manually, i have never gotten any continous number...
Can someone explain that to me?

Example Output:
25
26
27
...
...
1016
1017
1018
1019
1020
1021
1022
1023
1024

Does not look ver yRandom to me...?

Comment: You should run this through a debugger before you ask StackOverflow, and reduce it to a minimal reproducible issue. The problem is obvious once you do, and it is because your random numbers have no bearing on the result of the method call after the first run.

Comment: ((365 - 1) + 1)) is an interesting expression by the way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starter.start() returns the static "counter" value which is incremented by 1 after every iteration in the for loop , hence the output shows the output in increments of 1 .

Comment: Sort of, but this doesn't explain why the counter is updated only once inside the loop inside the method. The problem is that match is never false again.

Comment: why should match be false again? i dont see a single line where you would set match to false. If you want match to be false, you should set it to false at the beginning or end of the method

Comment: @SeanOwen : counter is always incremented by one inside the "do..while" loop for every "for" loop iteration as the match variable is never false again .

Comment: @jay that's all correct, I was suggesting that this observation is really what explains the error and might be useful in your answer then. I 100% agree with you. JohnnyAW, exactly, we agree.

Answer (score 2):

You are using static member variables for counter and match. That means they belong to the class and will not be reset between calls to start().

Since these variables are used only inside the start() method I suggest you put their declarations there as well.

```
public static int start() {
  boolean match = false;
  int counter = 0;
```

And remove the old declarations at the top.